# Can i get proper names for lighthouse reports without giving directory path while generating multiple lighthouse reports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, lighthouse

I was using the following code in batch file to generate lighthouse reports for multiple web pages:

```
@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("./url.txt"
) Do @LightHouse "%%A"  --disable-storage-reset --emulated-form-factor=desktop   --throttling-method=provided  --view --only-categories=performance,accessibility --output=json --output=html
```

And the files are getting stored in the following manner:

```
https://miro.medium.com/max/730/1*5cHRuTCcoDcrYbeE0sKZyg.png
```

url.txt:

```
https://miro.medium.com/max/875/1*aK5IeNvG9i4uZOCxgjhhvg.png
```

So can i get the file names with proper names just like last part of url or something like that by doing any modification in the code?

Comment: I just don't want to give output path because then only latest report will get stored in my local and i won't get all reports stored in my local (I won't get seperate reports in my local the latest report will replace previous report and finally the last report will be stored in my local).

Comment: My code is automatically generating reports for all urls and each web page report is getting stored separately as shown above. Now instead of reports with the above names is there any way to give such that they will get stored in my local with the last part of url (or any name i like).

Comment: Can i put last word in url as generated file name?